# Pine Script - How to select a candle stick bar with date time picker and draw horizontal lines at the high and low of this bar

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to draw hline (horizontal lines) at the high and low of a candle stick bar (15 minute time frame is a MUST) which I have selected from date time picker. As of now I can select the bar and highlight its background color to confirm that the date time picker is working fine. However I cannot draw horizontal lines at the high and low of this selected bar. The issue here is, I don't know how to get the high and low of the bar which I have selected from date time picker. Below is the code.

```
//@version=4
study("Price Channel with date range test", overlay=true)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("06 May 2021 04:30 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("06 May 2021 04:45 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
bgcolor(inDateRange ? color.lime : na, 90)

// Need code to get the high and low of this candle stick bar selected from the date time picker
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Code.

```
//@version=4
study("Price Channel with time range", overlay=true)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("07 May 2021 04:30 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("07 May 2021 04:30 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
bgcolor(inDateRange ? color.lime : na, 90)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 0.0

if inDateRange
    if not inDateRange[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

plot(not inDateRange ? highe_01 : na, title="High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, offset=-9999, trackprice=true)
plot(not inDateRange ? lowe_01: na, title="Low",  color=color.purple,  linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, offset=-9999, trackprice=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below gives you the option of having the lines to either: just to the right or across the whole chart (tick box in settings).

Is this what you are after?

```
//@version=4
study("Price Channel with time range", overlay=true)

i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("07 May 2021 04:30 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("07 May 2021 04:30 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
bgcolor(inDateRange ? color.lime : na, 90)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 0.0

if inDateRange
    if not inDateRange[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)

//plot(not inDateRange ? highe_01 : na, title="High", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
//plot(not inDateRange ? lowe_01: na, title="Low",  color=color.purple,  linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)

///////////////////////////////

showHigh = input(true, title="High", group="High Line", inline="1")
showLow = input(true, title="Low", group="Low Line", inline="1")

ExtendAxisLine = input(false, title="Extend lines across screen")
ExtendOption = ExtendAxisLine ? extend.both : extend.right

HighDateLine = (not inDateRange ? highe_01 : na)
var line ShowHighLine = na
if showHigh
    ShowHighLine := line.new(bar_index[1], HighDateLine, bar_index, HighDateLine, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)    
    line.delete(ShowHighLine[1])    

LowDateLine = (not inDateRange ? lowe_01 : na)
var line ShowLowLine = na
if showLow
    ShowLowLine := line.new(bar_index[1], LowDateLine, bar_index, LowDateLine, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=ExtendOption)    
    line.delete(ShowLowLine[1])
```

Comment: Hi frien_dd, you have already helped me in another query similar to this. Your code is really working for me. Many thanks. However this time, date time picker is a MUST for my requirement as I need the horizontal lines for a single DATE, which I MUST select from date time picker. Please look into my code. Is it possible, what I am asking ?

Comment: Apologies. Would the date that you will be analyzing go back further than a week?

Comment: why apologize ? you are helping me a lot.. I am thankful for this.. Yes the date can be any trading day in the past. Here I need 'hline' function rather than 'plot' function. I need the high and low of the particular candle(10:00 am to 10:15 am) for a date selected from date time picker, not a series of high low data for other candles of other days.

Comment: With little bit of luck and some portion of your code I solved it. Please look into my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sambit I have updated my question. If its not right can you manually draw it on a chart and upload.

Comment: thanks for your response. It gives me option to check or uncheck the lines. It will definitely help. However I have solved the plot extension by adding "trackprice=true" argument. Please look into the plot function of my code. For now it is sufficient for me.

Comment: I have another doubt, can you please help me ? I have posted the query here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67518300/15747004

Comment: I can't comment on your post as I don't have 50+ (used all my points on a question that I ended up answering myself!!). But I have just applied your code to BTCUSD on TF15 min and it works, what symbol are you using?

Comment: Yes it will work in some markets. In my case, the actual close time(and price) & last bar close time(and price) are different due to extended trading hours, that's why this price difference. Anyways, I have figured it out for my market. Thanks for your response :). I always appreciate your help.